# Ordinal Logistic Regression

Tags: econometrics, ordered-logit

My dataset looks like this:

```
Depen  Indep1 Indep2 Indep3
 1       1      1     Continous
 2       0      2
 3       1      3
 1       0      4
 2       1      1
 3       0      2
```

So as you can see I have an ordinal dependent variable with three categories, and one ordinal independent variable with four categories, I have one binary variable and one continuos variable. Can I run an ordinal logistic regression?(Depn ~ Indep1+Indep2+Indep3)

If not an ordinal logistic regression then which other models do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You can run an ordinal logistic regression with this setup as you have described. Interpreting ordinal logistic regression is not straightforward, so ensure you have a good resource for that.

If you don't want to assume that Depen is ordinal or you are unsure of its true order, you can run a multinomial logistic regression.